# Programmatically Add Add-In Macro to Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: excel, xml, vba, network-programming

I have a macro that formats an Excel report. This macro needs to run on many different workbooks as the report is generated and saved to a new file every day. This has been in my personal workbook. I now need to share this macro.

My plan is to have the add-in in my local addins folder. Make any updates there and run a routine which copies the addin to the network location and sets it to read only and hidden. Other users will not have the addin on their local machine so when they restart Excel the updates will take effect.

I created a "dummy Installer workbook" that will load the addin from the network location and make sure the user does not copy the addin to their local machine.

I would like this dummy workbook to add a button for the addin to the Quick Access Toolbar so I do not have to explain the process to the users. I have not found a way to do this while preserving the user's current UI settings. I imagine most of the users have not tweaked their UI very much if at all but I would rather not be responsible for messing up someone's UI.

I am still learning how to work with VBA and this is being deployed in a network environment which is also a little new to me.

Note:

- CommonSizeAR Code is in module1 of Common Size AR.xlam and DeployAddIn is in Module 2.
- Workbook_Open is stored in "this workbook" of Common Size AR installer.xlsm.

```vb
Private Sub deployAddIn()

    Dim strAddinDevelopmentPath As String
    Dim strAddinPublicPath As String 

    strAddinDevelopmentPath = "C:\AddIns" & Application.PathSeparator
    strAddinPublicPath = "W:\NetworkDrive" & Application.PathSeparator
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Save
        On Error Resume Next
        SetAttr strAddinPublicPath & .Name, vbNormal
        On Error GoTo 0
        .SaveCopyAs Filename:=strAddinPublicPath & .Name
        SetAttr strAddinPublicPath & .Name, vbReadOnly + vbHidden
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Private Sub workbook_open()

    Dim Result As Integer

    Result = MsgBox("Would you like to install the Common Size AR Add-in?", _
      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Install?")

    If Result = vbNo Then
        Application.ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    AddIns("Common Size AR").Installed = False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1

    AddIns.Add Filename:="W:\NetworkDrive\Common Size AR.xlam", Copyfile:=False
    AddIns("Common Size AR").Installed = True
    MsgBox "Add-in Installed!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Done!"
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler1:
    MsgBox "Install Failed! Please let Developer know", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error!"
    Exit Sub 

End Sub
```

Comment: Its been a year, and if you're reading this you are in luck because I figured out how to do this with ease.

When Creating the add in, as a final step customize the quick access toolbar for the workbook that the add in is saved as. 

When the Add in is loaded it will appear on the workbook for all workbooks. 

If you want to do this for an already saved add in youll have to go to the code set the "is addin" value to false, customize the toolbar, set "is addin" back to true and then save. 

TA DA!

Answer (score 0):

Run the Sub add menu - this will create the add ins tab, add the menu
with the button run the removemenu sub and it will take the adds in
menu tab and button away

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddMenu()
Dim Mycbar As CommandBar, Mycontrol As CommandBarControl, Mypopup As CommandBarPopup

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
RemoveMenu ' call remove routine to ensure only one menu in place

Set Mycbar = CommandBars.Add _
(Name:="TO's Menubar", Position:=msoBarBottom, Temporary:=False)
' create new commandbar (menu bar)

Set Mycontrol = Mycbar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
' create new commandbar control (button type) on custom menu
With Mycontrol
.Caption = "Smiley Yes/No" ' mouseover text
.Tag = "Smiley" ' used for identification
.OnAction = "MySub" ' macro called with control
.FaceId = 59 ' appearance, based on built-in faces
End With

Set Mypopup = Mycbar.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup)
' create new commandbar control (popup menu type) on custom menu
With Mypopup
.BeginGroup = True ' start new group
.Caption = "TO Menu Items" ' mouseover text
.Tag = "TOMenu" ' used for identification
End With

'============================================================================
'Add various sub-menu items to the popup control

Set Mycontrol = Mypopup.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
With Mycontrol
.Caption = "Text Converter" ' menu item description
.Tag = "Text Converter" ' used for identification
.OnAction = "TextCon" ' macro called with control
.FaceId = 59 ' appearance, based on built-in faces
End With

'===============================================================================

Mycbar.Visible = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Mycbar = Nothing 'release memory
Set Mycontrol = Nothing
Set Mypopup = Nothing

End Sub

Sub RemoveMenu()
Dim Mycbar As CommandBar

On Error Resume Next ' in case its already gone
Set Mycbar = CommandBars("TO's Menubar")
Mycbar.Delete
Set Mycbar = Nothing 'release memory

End Sub

Sub MySub()
Dim ans As Integer

ans = MsgBox("Do you want to remove the custom menu?", vbYesNo, "TO Custom Menu")
If ans = 6 Then RemoveMenu

End Sub

'text converter
Sub TextCon()
Dim ocell As Range, ans As String

ans = Application.InputBox("Type in Letter" & vbCr & _
"(L)owercase, (U)ppercase, (S)entence, (T)itles ")

If ans = "" Then Exit Sub

For Each ocell In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
Select Case UCase(ans)
Case "L": ocell = LCase(ocell.Text)
Case "U": ocell = UCase(ocell.Text)
Case "S": ocell = UCase(Left(ocell.Text, 1)) & _
LCase(Right(ocell.Text, Len(ocell.Text) - 1))
Case "T": ocell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(ocell.Text)
End Select
Next
End Sub
```