# Get name of the file from which the button was pressed on the toolbar

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in the personal.xlsb file to format current sheet. That macro is used in 2 ways

1. by pressing a button on the toolbar from any open file
2. by being called from another sub/procedure

I'm trying to write the macro, without using SELECT, ACTIVATE, PASTE, etc. (so, by declaring all workbooks and sheets and using WITH...). To do that, I have to know the name of the file that called the macro and it has to work for both being called from the button and from a procedure.

The code below is not fully functional because it's not switching between the two workbooks. I didn't finish coding because I realized that I don't know how to get the file and sheet name.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatTheBasics()

    Dim CurLastColumn As Long, CurLastRow As Long
    
    Dim CurRowNum As Long, LastRow As Long, FirstRowOfSection As Long, LastRowOfSection As Long
    Dim CurCell As Variant, CurRange As Range
    Dim wbkM  As Workbook, wbkC  As Workbook
    Dim wksReplaceWords As Worksheet, wksFilesToExportEMail  As Worksheet, wksCopyFrom   As Worksheet, wksCopyTo   As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopyFrom As Range, rngCopyTo As Range
    Dim x     As Long
    Dim CurColumnLetter As String, CurColumnName As String, ReplaceFrom As String, ReplaceTo As String

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
 
    Set wbkM = Workbooks("Personal.xlsb")
    Set wksReplaceWords = wbkM.Sheets("ReplaceWords")


    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = 1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    
    Range("A1:" & MyColumnLetter(xlLastCol) & "1").Select
    
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = 2
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
    Rows("2:2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
         
    For x = 1 To xlLastCol
         
        CurColumnLetter = MyColumnLetter(x)
        CurColumnName = StrConv(Range(CurColumnLetter & "1").Value, vbLowerCase)
        Range(CurColumnLetter & "1").Value = StrConv(CurColumnName, vbProperCase)
    
        CurRowNum = 2
    
        With wksReplaceWords
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Set CurRange = .Range("C" & CurRowNum & ":C" & LastRow)
            For Each CurCell In CurRange
                If CurCell <> "" Then
                
                    ReplaceFrom = .Range("B" & CurRowNum).Value
                    ReplaceTo = CurCell
 
                    If InStr(1, CurColumnName, ReplaceFrom, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
Range(CurColumnLetter & "1").Replace what:=ReplaceFrom, replacement:=ReplaceTo, MatchCase:=True

                    End If
    
                End If
            Next CurCell
        End With
              
    Next x
    
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Columns("A:" & MyColumnLetter(xlLastCol)).Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a VBA function, there is no means to find out where and why execution was started. To put it in programmer-speak, there is no way of introspecting call stack and execution context.

So how to solve this? Your best bet is to use `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveWorkbook` **once** only, assuming that the target workbooks' window was in front when the function was triggered. Store it into a variable and from then on use the Variable:

```
Public Sub DoStuff():
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Range("A1").value = "Hello World"
    ' ...
End Sub
```

This way, if you find flaws in your sheet-detection logic, you just need to improve the code right at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Tool bar is not workbook specific.  meaning the tool bar is not in the xls file.  you can add it  via code.  but it will stay there for all excel sheets.
[Programmatically Add Add-In Macro to Quick Access Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870338/programmatically-add-add-in-macro-to-quick-access-toolbar)

Activeshheet gives the sheet the cursor is on that calls the macro.  SO one sheet has the common macro.  And another calls it.  The macro sheet doesn't need to be opened once the macro is attached to the tool bar.

Active, select, paste is bad because of the issue you are asking help on.   A macro can be running.  An then move the cursor to another sheet the macro will pick up the new sheet.  So good practice is grab the worksheet(active) at the beginning of the macro an use that for the rest.
Using a toolbar macro will call the closed sheet's macro and use the active sheet references.  The hard part is using the macro to update the non active sheet without hard coding a file name.

Comment: sorry the toolbar can be edited by code.  It is a customXML in the XLSB file. Unizip the excel file to find them.   The internal files can be modified with vba code.  Lot of work. 
 https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/document-level-customui-editor.htm.  insight.  there might be an excel style/macro file someplace

Comment: hey, thank you!! but my problem isn't just clicking from the toolbar. i have the same problem when i call that macro from another procedure. i think the answer above explains why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

On the button attached procedure include

```
strFileFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

To get the desired active workbook filename

Comment: This gives personal.xlsb

Comment: Is that the file you clicked the button

Comment: No, that's the problem:) someone already answered below. There's no way to get it without using activate first