# Excel VBA Customize QAT

Tags: excel, vba, office365

My old laptop died and I replaced it.  After installing Excel I ran a small VBA macro to setup Options the way I like them.  One of the things that macro does not do is to setup the QAT.

For example, I would like to add *PasteSpecialFormats* to the QAT.  I did this manually with the Macro Recorder on.  The Recorder did not capture this change.

I am using Office 365 in a Win 10 Home environment.  Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason behind using VBA? Will it not be one time only?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870338 perhaps?

Comment: @CLR  Thanks......I will investigate.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij  You are correct...the only reason is I already have a macro that does 80% of he setup.

Comment: Looks like editing the registry (when Excel is not open) https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/customize-backup-quick-access-toolbar-settings-file-explorer/ Quote Cindy Meister: "The QAT is meant for user customizations, which is why it's not "exposed" directly to the developer. There is a QAT file that holds the customizations, but this cannot be edited while the Office application is opened."